# VB sql searching error "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Im trying to make a search where you can input either `ID` or `Name` but when I try to input a name it display the error

> "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

Here is my code:

```
 If button1 = 2 Then
        Dim SA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select [Dept_Id],[Dept_Name],[Active] From [it].[dbo].[Department] WHERE Dept_Id = '" & frmMain.txtSearch.Text & "' OR Dept_Name='" & frmMain.txtSearch.Text & "'", Connection1)
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        SA.Fill(DT)
        With D
            .DataSource = DT
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Department ID"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Department Name"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Active"
        End With
```

There is an error in line `SA.Fill(DT)`

Comment: `Dept_Id` is probably a `bigint`, but you're treating it as a string (`nvarchar`). Also, your code is *extremely* vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. For the sake of your users, please learn how to use prepared statements / parameterized queries.

Comment: You should NEVER use user input to generate an sql statement.  I can't explain to whole thing in a single comment but google sql injection for more details.

Comment: sorry im new to vb. What should i do?

Comment: or he could just write a stored procedure, but I am guessing there is a lack of understanding about data types ... and working with them

Answer (score 3):

You should use parameters for the query.  And, I might question why you would want user input that would be either a name or a number.  But, given what you are doing, you can fix your problem by converting `Dept_Id` before the comparison:

```
Select [Dept_Id], [Dept_Name], [Active]
From [it].[dbo].[Department]
WHERE CAST(Dept_Id as VARCHAR(255)) = '" & frmMain.txtSearch.Text & "' OR 
      Dept_Name='" & frmMain.txtSearch.Text & "'"
```

This is also one way to approach the solution even with a parametrized query.